# ASP.NET Web API return ArrayList as JSON

Tags: asp.net, json, vb.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm new to web API, and all the examples are in C# which doesn't help, as such I've hit a roadblock early on. I'm returning data from SQL, putting it an object array list, and then trying to return it so it could be read by a JSON client.

This is my default GET on my controller:

```
Function Index() As IEnumerable(Of String)
            Dim Sites As New ArrayList
            Dim dt As DataTable = DataLayer.ExecuteNoParamStoredProcedure("stored_proc", "connection_string")

            For Each r As DataRow In dt.Rows()
                Sites.Add(New SiteDetails(r("SiteName"),r("SiteId")))
            Next

            Return Sites
        End Function
```

And here is my SiteDetails class:

```
Public Class SiteDetails
Public site As String
Public siteid As String

Public Sub New(sitename As String, id As String)
    site = sitename
    siteid = id
End Sub
End Class
```

Questions: How to I make it output the data on the page in a format that isn't either an error or just the object name? Is there a better way to do what I'm doing?

Joe

**EDIT** just to comment, the above doesn't work from the off, because it can't the return type (IEnumerable(Of String)) doesn't allow an arraylist to be returned, this is the bulk of my issue.

Comment: DO NOT ever use `ArrayList`. This is still there only for backwards compatibility to old code. Use strongly-typed `List (Of T)` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your sample, you return an `IEnumerable(Of String)`. Therefore, when returning the result of your action method, all objects are converted to a string by calling the `ToString` method (I suspect you have OPTION STRING turned OFF in your project); in your case, the default implementation of `ToString` is used. This implementation returns the name of the type.

In order to return the data, I'd change the code as follows:

- If you want to return all object properties, change the signature of your action method to `Function Index() As IEnumerable(Of SiteDetails)`
- If you want to return some strings, leave the signature of your action method as it is, but override the `ToString` method of the SiteDetails class so that the required data are formatted as a string correctly.

In addition, I'd propose not to use the `ArrayList` class anymore; there is a strongly typed `List(Of T)` class (in your case `List(Of SiteDetails)` if you want to return the SiteDetails objects or `List(Of String)` if you want to return strings).

---

Also, make sure that you are using a Web API controller. These controllers are derived from the `ApiController` class (as opposed to a MVC controller that looks roughly the same, but is derived from `System.Web.Mvc.Controller`).

Comment: In all honesty, I only loosely grasp what you mean, I've amended as follows: changed my return type to `As IEnumerable(Of SiteDetails)` and changed my sites array to be: `Dim Sites As New List(Of SiteDetails)` - the output on the page is now `System.Collections.Generic.List`1[OnsiteAPI.SiteDetails]` - where did I go wrong? Thanks for getting back to me btw :)

Comment: On which page are you putting the output? I've created a sample project with your `SiteDetails` class and a `List(Of SiteDetails)` in a method that returns `IEnumerable(Of SiteDetails)`. In Edge, the data is shown in JSON format: [{"site":"site1","siteid":"1"},{"site":"site2","siteid":"2"}].

Comment: Does your controller class inherit from `ApiController`? It seems that you are using a MVC controller instead of a Web API controller. In the sample project, you should put the API code into the ValuesController; the HomeController class is a MVC controller. I've put my sample code into HomeController and the result is `System.Collections.Generic.List``1[TestWebAPI.SiteDetails]` as in your comment. So it seems that you are not using a API controller.

Comment: I feel like a fool! This fixed it, it was in fact an MVC controller, not a web API controller, thanks! :D

Comment: You're welcome-the differences are really small so it can be easily overlooked in the heat of the action.